# Show $f(x^2 + y^2 , \ln(\frac{x}{y}))$ is a solution to a partial differential equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Given function is $z = f(x^2 + y^2, \ln(x/y))$
Let $z = f(u,v)$, let $u = x^2 + y^2, v = \ln(x/y)$, show that $z$ satisfies the equation 
$$x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2u \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$$

Comment: Please finish writing out your post.

Comment: It would help if we knew what the equation was...

Comment: edit: i have no idea how to write the partial symbol

Comment: Just substitute the proposed solution and check the equation is satisfied.

Comment: Perhaps OP is having difficulty calculating ${\partial z\over\partial x}$ and/or ${\partial z\over\partial y}$ and/or ${\partial z\over\partial u}$. Is that the difficulty?

Comment: Dunno guys...the question as posed looks clear to me, see answer below.  I nominate for reopening.

Comment: Isophyxen: when you receive an answer that is helpful, it's a good idea to accept such an answer. You can accept ONE answer per question, and to accept an answer, you can simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You get two reputation points for each answer you accept, and it's a way to say "thank you."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule.

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2 x \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 2 y \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} - \frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$$

$$x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  + y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2 (x^2 + y^2) \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = 2 u \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$$

as was to be shown.